# How to remove list item after typing a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the following code below. I want to remove a single list item every time someone types the string remove in. I used a while True loop. I tried to replace it with "for x in string" to iterate over the loop but that did not work. I am clearly a beginner so anything would greatly help.

I want them to be able to see the list every time something is removed and then be able to hit enter to remove another single list item.

```
import random


first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth = input("Name the first item in your dream house? "), input("Name the second item in your dream house? "), input("Name the third item in your dream house? "), input("Name the fourth item in your dream house? "), input("Name the fifth item in your dream house? "), input("Name the sixth item in your dream house? "), input("Name the seventh item in your dream house? "), input("Name the eigth item in your dream house? "), input("Name the ninth item in your dream house? "), input("Name the tenth item in your dream house? ")

list = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eigth, ninth, tenth]

while True:
  try:
    if input() == "remove":
      list.remove(random.choice(list)) 
      print(list)
      break
  except:
    break
```

Comment: Do you want to remove a specific item from the list or have a random item removed everytime the user types a string? The first one will remove the string the user typed, the second will just need the user to type something random. What happens when the list gets empty? Should the program stop or reset itself?

Comment: I want an item removed every time and then printed out. It doesnt matter what happens there is no list items left.

Comment: I have updated my response with both options. Compare your code and let me know if you need help with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this to add and delete from your list. If you want to use random, then you can replace `out` with `random.choice`.  If you use random, dont forget to import random.

I have used walrus operator. Example of [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/) is in the link shared.

## Code to remove random items from the list

```
import random
home_list = []
i = 1
while (choice := input ('Enter the item for your dream house :')) != 'done':
    home_list.append(choice.lower())
    
#example of [walrus statement](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/)
print ('The full list of items for your dream home are: \n', home_list) 

while (out := input ('Do you want to remove anything from the list :')) != 'done':
    home_list.remove(random.choice(home_list)) 
    if not home_list: #check if list is empty
        print ('That was the last item on your list')
        break
    
    print ('The remaining list of items for your dream home are: \n', home_list)
```

## Code with option to remove specific item from list

```
home_list = []
i = 1
while (choice := input ('Enter the item for your dream house :')) != 'done':
    home_list.append(choice.lower())
    
print ('The full list of items for your dream home are: \n', home_list) 

while (out := input ('Do you want to remove anything from the list :')) != 'done':
    if out.lower() in home_list:
        home_list.remove(out.lower()) #remove the item from the list
        if not home_list: #check if list is empty
            print ('That was the last item on your list')
            break
    else:
        print ('Sorry, that item is not in your current list')
        
    print ('The remaining list of items for your dream home are: \n', home_list)
```

Comment: Review the response above and let me know if this addresses your question. Also please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
lim=0
lis=list()
while lim<=10:
    print("s")
    lis.append(input("Name the first item in your dream house? "))
    lim=lim+1

while True:
  print("Please enter \"remove\" for remove a random list item")  
  try:
    if input() == "remove":
      lis.remove(random.choice(lis)) 
      print(lis)
      continue
  except:
    break
```